# XSLT Stylesheet driving me crazy

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm having this piece of XML code:

```
<HushållRegister>
<Hushåll>
<Hushåll_UpdSignatur>cleveland</Hushåll_UpdSignatur>
<Hushåll_UpdDatum>040213</Hushåll_UpdDatum>
<Hushåll_Tom>20010218</Hushåll_Tom>
<Hushåll_From>19991026</Hushåll_From>
<Hushåll_HushållNr>1111</Hushåll_HushållNr>
<OmfattasRegister>
<Omfattas>
<Omfattas_Namn>Tomason, Tomas</Omfattas_Namn>
<Omfattas_Personnummer>166666666666</Omfattas_Personnummer>
</Omfattas>
</OmfattasRegister>
</Hushåll>
<Hushåll>
<Hushåll_UpdSignatur>cleveland</Hushåll_UpdSignatur>
<Hushåll_UpdDatum>040213</Hushåll_UpdDatum>
<Hushåll_Tom>20010218</Hushåll_Tom>
<Hushåll_From>19991026</Hushåll_From>
<Hushåll_HushållNr>1111</Hushåll_HushållNr>
<OmfattasRegister>
<Omfattas>
<Omfattas_Namn>Tomason, Tomas</Omfattas_Namn>
<Omfattas_Personnummer>166666666666</Omfattas_Personnummer>
</Omfattas>
<Omfattas>
<Omfattas_Namn>Anderson, Carl</Omfattas_Namn>
<Omfattas_Personnummer>177777777777</Omfattas_Personnummer>
</Omfattas>
<Omfattas>
<Omfattas_Namn>Clarkson, Clark</Omfattas_Namn>
<Omfattas_Personnummer>188888888888</Omfattas_Personnummer>
</Omfattas>
<Omfattas>
<Omfattas_Namn>Johnson, John</Omfattas_Namn>
<Omfattas_Personnummer>199999999999</Omfattas_Personnummer>
</Omfattas>
</OmfattasRegister>
</Hushåll>
</HushållRegister>
```

To render this I'm using this piece of XSL code:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//Gallringsundantag_i_Procapita/Person/*[name() = 'HushållRegister']">
    <tr bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Gallringsundantag_i_Procapita/Person/HushållRegister/*">
    <tr bgcolor="#E0FFFF">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="//Gallringsundantag_i_Procapita/Person/HushållRegister/Hushåll/*[not(self::OmfattasRegister)]">

    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>

    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Gallringsundantag_i_Procapita/Person/HushållRegister/Hushåll/OmfattasRegister">

    <tr bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
    </tr>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This gives me the following table rows in HTML:

```
HushållRegister 
Hushåll 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
OmfattasRegister 
OmfattasRegister 
Hushåll 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
OmfattasRegister 
OmfattasRegister
```

However, what I'm looking for according to the content of the XML is like this:

```
HushållRegister 
Hushåll 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
OmfattasRegister 
Omfattas
Hushåll 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
Hushåll_UpdSignatur 
Hushåll_UpdDatum 
Hushåll_Tom 
Hushåll_From 
Hushåll_HushållNr 
OmfattasRegister 
Omfattas
Omfattas
Omfattas
Omfattas
```

The problem seems to be that both tags "OmfattasRegister" are read instead of first looping in to the first instance of "OmfattasRegister" to get the only "Omfattas" there and then move on to the next "Hushåll" so that the next "OmfattasRegister" can be rendered to get the 4 "Omfattas" there. Instead the "OmfattasRegister" is duplicated twice.

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks for your efforts.

/Paul

Comment: Please make it easy for us and (1) explain in words the logic you want to apply in the transformation and (b) show the expected output **as code**. Minimizing the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem would be appreciated, too - see: [mcve].

Comment: Michael, the table rows are presented in the order they occur when the XML-file is rendered with the stylesheet. Perhaps I don't understand how to present the output as code.

Comment: Please think of a title that describes your problem. "driving me crazy" is not useful for anyone, neither now nor in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Gallringsundantag_i_Procapita/Person/HushållRegister/Hushåll/OmfattasRegister">
```

processes all 'OmfattasRegister' nodes, regardless of where in the hierarchy they are.

If you replaced it with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OmfattasRegister">
```

it will process only the 'OmfattasRegister' nodes that are a child of your current Hushåll node.